# Conditional Approval Levels Based On Product

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement to get the approval limit based on the product amount.
E.g.
 -   If the product amount is less than 10000, then get the corresponding approval person.

- If the product amount is greater than 10000 and less than 50000, then get the corresponding approval person and person below 10000 limit
- If the product amount is greater than 50000 and less than 100000, then get the corresponding approval person and all persons below 50000 limit
- If the product amount is greater than 100000 and less than 500000, then get the corresponding approval person and all persons below 100000 limit

Is it possible to achieve this without hard coding the product amount and approval limit, which means it should be dynamic because values in the table changes.

Comment: I'm not sure this is clear still; can you add the result you expect to see, and what you've tried so far? (Also not sure why you have duplicated/denormalised data in `pos_t`, but hopefully this is just a demo)

Comment: Your case expression doesn't match anything on exactly 50000, which I imagine is a mistake; you only need the `<` check in each branch? But with that it should match superiors 2, 3 and 4; why are you expecting it to match 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you just need to join your tables togather:

```
select pos_t.*
from prod_t
join pos_t on pos_t.username = prod_t.username
and pos_t.approval_limit <= prod_t.product_amt
where prod_t.prod_id = 'BC45'
and prod_t.product_amt = 50000;

USERNAME             NAME            POSITION        SUPERIOR_POSITION_LEVEL_ID SUPERIOR_POSITION_NAME    SUPERIOR_NAME   SUPERIOR_USERNAME SUPERIOR_P APPROVAL_LIMIT
-------------------- --------------- --------------- -------------------------- ------------------------- --------------- ----------------- ---------- --------------
C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             1 Sen.Analyst               Ford            12735                    782          10000
C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             2 Manager                   Smith           329822                  6218          50000
```

With `product_amt` of 12000 it only returns senior position 1; for 120000 it returns 1, 2 and 3; for 500000 it returns 1, 2, 3 and 4. That seems to be what you are describing and expecting.

If you only have the `prod_id` then you can get the levels for all values, in which case you need a `distinct`:

```
select distinct pos_t.*
from prod_t
join pos_t on pos_t.username = prod_t.username
and pos_t.approval_limit <= prod_t.product_amt
where prod_t.prod_id = 'BC45';

USERNAME             NAME            POSITION        SUPERIOR_POSITION_LEVEL_ID SUPERIOR_POSITION_NAME    SUPERIOR_NAME   SUPERIOR_USERNAME SUPERIOR_P APPROVAL_LIMIT
-------------------- --------------- --------------- -------------------------- ------------------------- --------------- ----------------- ---------- --------------
C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             1 Sen.Analyst               Ford            12735                    782          10000
C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             4 Chief Executive           Scott           13457                   2987         500000
C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             2 Manager                   Smith           329822                  6218          50000
C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             3 General Manager Finance   Jack            23512                    727         100000
```

Or find the highest `product_amt` for that `prod_id` and restrict to that, which will get the same answer but will be more efficient, for example with something like:

```
select pos_t.*
from (
  select max(username) keep (dense_rank last order by product_amt) as username,
    max(product_amt) as product_amt
  from prod_t
  where prod_id = 'BC45'
) prod_t
join pos_t on pos_t.username = prod_t.username
and pos_t.approval_limit <= prod_t.product_amt;

USERNAME             NAME            POSITION        SUPERIOR_POSITION_LEVEL_ID SUPERIOR_POSITION_NAME    SUPERIOR_NAME   SUPERIOR_USERNAME SUPERIOR_P APPROVAL_LIMIT
-------------------- --------------- --------------- -------------------------- ------------------------- --------------- ----------------- ---------- --------------
C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             1 Sen.Analyst               Ford            12735                    782          10000
C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             2 Manager                   Smith           329822                  6218          50000
C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             3 General Manager Finance   Jack            23512                    727         100000
C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             4 Chief Executive           Scott           13457                   2987         500000
```

Or if you want the matching data for each `product_amt` at the same time, you can just leave out the `distinct`, and include the amount so you know which it's matching:

```
select prod_t.product_amt, pos_t.*
from prod_t
join pos_t on pos_t.username = prod_t.username
and pos_t.approval_limit <= prod_t.product_amt
where prod_t.prod_id = 'BC45';

PRODUCT_AMT USERNAME             NAME            POSITION        SUPERIOR_POSITION_LEVEL_ID SUPERIOR_POSITION_NAME    SUPERIOR_NAME   SUPERIOR_USERNAME SUPERIOR_P APPROVAL_LIMIT
----------- -------------------- --------------- --------------- -------------------------- ------------------------- --------------- ----------------- ---------- --------------
     120000 C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             1 Sen.Analyst               Ford            12735                    782          10000
     500000 C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             1 Sen.Analyst               Ford            12735                    782          10000
      50000 C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             1 Sen.Analyst               Ford            12735                    782          10000
      12000 C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             1 Sen.Analyst               Ford            12735                    782          10000
     120000 C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             2 Manager                   Smith           329822                  6218          50000
     500000 C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             2 Manager                   Smith           329822                  6218          50000
      50000 C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             2 Manager                   Smith           329822                  6218          50000
     120000 C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             3 General Manager Finance   Jack            23512                    727         100000
     500000 C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             3 General Manager Finance   Jack            23512                    727         100000
     500000 C1256                James           Fin. Analyst                             4 Chief Executive           Scott           13457                   2987         500000
```

Comment: I can only pass prod_id as parameter

Comment: All the `prod_t` rows in your example have the same `prod_id`. So if you only filter on that column, what output do you want? The `pos_t` matching the highest `product_amt` for that `prod_id`? All that match any amount (which is going to be the same thing)?

Answer (score 1):

I think You need something like this:

```
with amounts as (
  select username, nvl(lag(product_amt) over (order by product_amt), 0) amt1, 
         product_amt amt2 
    from prod_t where username = 'C1256' and prod_id = 'BC45')
select amt1, amt2, approval_limit, superior_name, 
    case when amt1 < approval_limit then 'PRIMARY' else 'SECONDARY' end as type
  from amounts
    join pos_t on amounts.username = pos_t.username and approval_limit <= amt2
  where amt1 < 50000 and 50000 <= amt2
  order by amt2, approval_limit desc;


=========================================================================


      AMT1       AMT2 APPROVAL_LIMIT SUPERIOR_NAME    TYPE
---------- ---------- -------------- ---------------- ---------
     12000      50000          50000 Smith            PRIMARY
     12000      50000          10000 Ford             SECONDARY
```

The query below shows main approval person(s) in column `list1` and secondary in `list2`, sorted by their level. The assignment is built dynamically depending on values in `prod_t`.

```
with amounts as (
  select row_number() over (order by product_amt) rn, 
         nvl(lag(product_amt) over (order by product_amt), 0) amt1, 
         product_amt amt2 
    from prod_t)
select rn, amt1, amt2, 
       (select listagg(superior_name, ',') 
               within group (order by pos_t.superior_position_level_id desc) 
          from pos_t where amt1 < approval_limit and approval_limit <= amt2) list1,  
       (select listagg(superior_name||' ('||approval_limit||')', ',') 
               within group (order by pos_t.superior_position_level_id desc)
          from pos_t where approval_limit <= amt1) list2
  from amounts
  order by rn


=========================================================================


    RN       AMT1       AMT2 LIST1     LIST2
------ ---------- ---------- --------- ------------------------------------------
     1          0      12000 Ford     
     2      12000      50000 Smith     Ford (10000)
     3      50000     120000 Jack      Smith (50000),Ford (10000)
     4     120000     500000 Scott     Jack (100000),Smith (50000),Ford (10000)
```

---

> Is it possible to do without with and as statements?

Yes, like here:

```
select amt1, amt2, approval_limit, superior_name,
    case when amt1 < approval_limit then 'PRIMARY' else 'SECONDARY' end type
  from (
    select username, nvl(lag(product_amt) over (order by product_amt), 0) amt1,
           product_amt amt2
      from prod_t where username='C1256' and prod_id = 'BC45') amounts
    join pos_t on amounts.username = pos_t.username and approval_limit <= amt2
  where amt1 < 50000 and 50000 <= amt2
  order by amt2, approval_limit desc
```